# How to get names of relevant ID's from 2 different tables and display them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, First one has the product ID and Name, Second one has Supplier ID and name, In the 3rd one i have product ID and Supplier ID. While displaying, i want to replace the product ID and supplier ID in the 3rd table with product name and supplier name from the 1st and 2nd table respectively.
Please let me know the query for executing it.

Comment: Do a `JOIN` between the tables.

Comment: @Rahul - I know that. I dont know the query to do so. :|

Comment: If you want the exact query, you should specify the exact column names and exact table names in your question, otherwise you need to do a find and replace in the query.

Comment: @sealocal: table1 = product_master, column1 = product_nbr
table 2 = stockist_master, column2 = stockist_nbr
table 3 = stockist_product_offer, Column3= product_nbr and stockist_nbr. I want to replace the product_nbr and stockist_nbr in table 3 with product_name and stockis_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.id
INNER JOIN table3
ON table2.id=table3.id;
```

If your tables are named `products_master`, `stockists_master`, and `stockist_product_offer`, then you can join the tables and select any of the six columns that you want.

```
SELECT product_master.name, stockists_master.name
FROM products_master
INNER JOIN stockist_product_offer
ON product_master.id = stockist_product_offer.product_id
INNER JOIN stockists_master
ON stockist_product_offer.stockist_id = stockist.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to **join** the tables on IDs so the query is :
let s say that :
* first table : product
* second table : supplier
* third table : match

```
SELECT P.PRODUCTNAME
       S.SUPPLIERNAME
FROM
       PRODUCT P
INNER JOIN
       MATCH M
ON     P.PRODUCTID = M.PRODUCTID  
INNER JOIN 
       SUPPLIER S
ON     S.SUPPLIERID = M.SUPPLIERID
ORDER BY  1
;
```

Comment: The name of the tables are product_master, stockists_master and sotckist_product_offer

Comment: this is what we call alias , so you can give the table an alias name so you can use it easly, p = product :) you can change the name as it s

Comment: Thanks mate :) Made the task easier :)